# How to enable HTTPS for VS Code Live Server extension?

Tags: https, server, live

I have installed OpenSSL and created a certificate and private key. I used the configuration from [this page](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/blob/master/docs/settings.md) (shown below) but when I use [live server extension](https://ritwickdey.github.io/vscode-live-server/) from VS Code, it says "Connection not secured" and "Certificate is Invalid".

`liveServer.settings.https`: To enable https protocol.

Properties :

```
 "liveServer.settings.https": {
    "enable": false, //set it true to enable the feature.
    "cert": "C:\\https\\server.cert", //full path
    "key": "C:\\https\\server.key", //full path
    "passphrase": "12345"
},
```

Comment: This is normal, as self-signed certificates are untrusted by default (see https://security.stackexchange.com/q/112768). You can either click through the warning, since the validity of the certificate does not matter in your case, or you can jump through some hoops to get your browser to trust the self-signed cert.